# How can I clean product names in python that have misspelled in typing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, listview, arraylist

I have a dataset with these columns: CLIENT NAMES, PRODUCT CATEGORY, PRODUCT NAMES and ID. In the column of PRODUCT NAMES, most of the products have been misspelled like switched up letters, incomplete names, typed wrongly etc.  We have 7000 different product names in our database. I am looking for python script that can correct misspelled product names.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am not so sure about this because unless you have the correct names in another place/column. As well as if there is none, because if you use a spell checker some specific product may be spelled wrong.

Comment: But really interesting question man

Comment: Yes @TroyD, There is a column of correct names but the issue is to know which name among the correct ones, the person wanted to type and then correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try a [language-check](https://github.com/myint/language-check).

**Requirements:**

- Python v3.3+ (or 2.7)
- Java v6.0 or higher.

Maybe something like this (I didn't test)...

Let's say `PRODUCT_NAMES` is an extracted column from your database.

```py
import language_check
tool = language_check.LanguageTool('en-US')

PRODUCT_NAMES = ["switched", "bycucle"]

NEW_PRODUCT_NAMES = []
for item in PRODUCT_NAMES:
    matches = tool.check(item)
    suggestion = language_check.correct(item, matches)
    NEW_PRODUCT_NAMES.append(suggestion)
```

Comment: Hey bro, there is a 'Correct names' column, so u just need to, just replace the stuff